# 'Unable to read file' when importing rendered video file into Adobe Premiere 2020

Tags: rendering, video, external-applications, encoding

So I'm attempting to import a rendered Blender video file into Adobe Premiere. However, it just comes up with a message saying 'unable to read file' or something of the like. I have tried four different file formats (`.avi`,`.mp4`,`.mkv` and `.mov`) and neither of them work.

And yes, I am aware that this could (and probably is) be an issue with Adobe Premiere, but I also think that maybe the selected file format that I chose in Blender ('FFMpeg Video') might have something to do about it. Plus, I'm unable to open the file (in any format) to QuickTime Player, although for some reason other video that aren't made in Blender or by me are completely fine.

So two things.

1. Does the rendered file format selected in Blender affect how this works and what it should be if I want a video format?
2. Is there anything wrong with Premiere that is prohibiting the files from being able to be read?

*Btw, I have an Apple computer.*

Comment: AFAIK quicktime is dead, latest release is [from 2016](https://support.apple.com/downloads/quicktime). Test the file using the latest VLC player. Also I'd suggest never encode your renderings directly, render as image sequence and the use ffmpeg/handbrake/premiere or whatever to compile the images into a clip as additional step.

Comment: What codec are you using?